# How to get Solana program name

Tags: solana-program, spl

Is there a way to get the name of a Solana program, e.g. receive `"Compute Budget Program"` for `"ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111"`?

Answer (score 1):

The Solana guys have an extensive lookup in their explorer [here](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/6f2e556b1653a5cd34418a705d9aa4f50eb295e5/explorer/src/utils/tx.ts). It may not be as complete as some of the other explorers. But at least, it is open-source.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible.  Personally I have a JSON with all the program IDs and the names I want to put there